# How to solve $\sqrt{ 4 - x^2} > 1 - x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have to solve the inequality:

$$\sqrt{4-x^2} > 1 - x$$

in $\mathbb{R}$. Obviously we have to apply the condition of $x \in (-\infty, 2] \cup [2, +\infty)$ for the square root to be defined. But after that I have a few problems.

There is no problem for the case when we have $1-x \ge 0$ since both sides of the inequality would be positive so I could just square both sides of the inequality (since the inequality sign would not change) and find an answer. However, the case when we have $1-x < 0$ (so $x \in (1, +\infty)$) confuses me. When does the inequality sign change and when does it not? Or if that is not how I should I approach this case, how should I?

Comment: Hint: a square root of a non-negative real is defined to be non-negative.

Comment: The domain of validity, on the contrary, is $[-2;2]$.

Comment: Um $(-\infty, 2]\cup [2,+\infty) = \mathbb R$.  If the square root is defined then $4-x^2 \ge 0$ and $x^2 \le 4$ and so $-2 \le x \le 2$ and $x \in [-2, 2]$.

Comment: $1-x \ge 0\iff x \ge 1$ so for $2\ge x\ge 1$ then $4-x^2 > (1-x)^2$.  But if $-2 \le x< 1$ then $\sqrt{4-x^2}\ge 0 > 1-x$ and you don't have to do a dang thing.  It's done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the square root to be defined we need $x^{2} \leq 4$ or $-2 \leq x \leq 2$. If $1-x <0$ then the given inequality holds automatically. So very number in $(1,2]$ is a solution. For $-2 \leq x <1$ we have $4-x^{2} >(1-x)^{2}=x^{2}-2x+1$ or $2x^{2}-2x-3<0$. This can be written as $(x-\frac  1 2 )^{2} <7/4$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need $$ x\in [-2, 2]$$ for the square root to be real. $$ \sqrt{4-x^2} > 1 - x$$

That said, the inequality holds if $$ 1-x<0$$

On the other hand if $$1-x\ge 0 $$ we square both sides and get the solution for the quadratic inequality which is $$x\in (\frac {1-\sqrt 7}{2}, \frac {1+\sqrt 7}{2})$$

Thus the solution is  intersection of the acceptable regions  which is the inteval $$S=(\frac {1-\sqrt 7}{2},2]$$